# Displaying CGI results in PHP webpage

Tags: python, php, cgi

I have a php code that has a form . The action tag in the form includes a CGI script (updated.py) as the following :

```
<form id="phpbasics" name="phpbasics" method="GET" action="http://localhost:8888//cgi-bin/updated.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

when I submit the form the CGI result is displayed in another page . I need the cgi results to be displayed in my php page.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use an `iframe` and embed this form into it. You can then use `postMessage` to the `window.parent` and the parent window can execute methods within the iframe if need be.

Comment: Great ! That actually worked !!! Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome. I suggest adding your solution as an Answer for future viewers.

Comment: sure . I will . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
<form target = "mypage.php" id="phpbasics" name="phpbasics" method="GET" action="http://localhost:8888//cgi-bin/updated.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then I used Iframe

```
<iframe name="mypage.php"></iframe>
```